# Why does this epsilon-delta proof for $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac1x=1$ not work?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I do not understand what is wrong with this $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that is supposed to show $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x} = 1$

We have to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that for all $x$ that satisfy $0 < \left| x - 1\right| <\delta$ the following is implied: $\left|\dfrac{1}{x} - 1\right| < \epsilon$

Here is how I started:
$$
\left|\dfrac{1}{x} - 1\right| < \epsilon \implies\dfrac{\left|x-1\right|}{\left|x\right|} < \epsilon\\ 
$$
To bound the $\left|x\right|$, let $\delta = 1$ then
$$\begin{align*}
& \left|x - 1\right| < 1\\
\implies& |x| - |1| \leq \left|x - 1\right|  < 1\\
\implies& |x| < 2\\[1em]
\implies& |x-1|<\epsilon|x|<2\epsilon
\end{align*}$$
So if we let $\delta = \min\left(1,\, 2\epsilon\right)$, all $x$ that satisfy $0<|x - 1|< \delta$ should also satisfy $\left|\dfrac{1}{x} - 1\right| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, but that is not the case if you take a look at a graph.

Comment: The last statement is false. Observe that for $\epsilon=1/3$ we have that $0<|x-1|<2/3\implies x\in(-1,1/3)\cup(1,5/3)$ and, at the same time, we have that $\frac{|x-1|}{|x|}<1/3$, but choosing $x=1/4$ we have that $3<1/3$, what is not possible.

Comment: Your order of conclusion is wrong from the first line (that would be right if you put an `\iff` $\iff$ there for equivalency). In the end the proof of continuity requires exactly the reverse direction in all of the arrows, and not all of the transformations are to equivalent inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left|\dfrac{1}{x} - 1\right| < \epsilon \implies\dfrac{\left|x-1\right|}{\left|x\right|} < \epsilon$

Great up to here

To bound the $|x|$, let $δ=1$ uh oh...look at what follows

$|x−1|<1\\
0< x<1\\
\frac {|x-1|}{x} < \infty$

Not going to work.  You need a tighter bound for $\delta$

let $\delta = \frac 12$

$|x|> \frac 12\\
|\frac {1-x}{x}| < 2|1-x|<2\delta<\epsilon\\
\delta = \min(\frac 12, \frac \epsilon 2)$

Comment: I see, if I let $\delta$ equal any value less than 1, it will work? It seems to work for $\dfrac{99}{100}$

Comment: It will work so long as you can create a lower bound for $x$ that is greater than $0$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality
$$\vert x - 1 \vert < \epsilon \vert x \vert$$
doesn't follow from the previous line. You need an upper bound on $\vert x \vert$. To get that, just pick $\delta = \min(\epsilon/2,1/2)$. Then $\vert x - 1 \vert < \delta$ implies that $\vert x \vert > 1/2$, so we have
$$\frac{\vert x - 1 \vert}{\vert x \vert} < \frac{\epsilon/2}{1/2} = \epsilon.$$

Comment: I can see that letting $\delta = 1$ allows $\frac{1}{x}$ to get arbritarily large, which went against the whole point of bounding $|x - 1|$, but how does $|x - 1| < \epsilon|x|$ not follow from $\dfrac{|x-1|}{|x|}< \epsilon$? Multiplying both sides by $|x|$ results in $|x - 1| < \epsilon|x|$. Is that not legal?